# How to import/export Spyder preferences?

Tags: spyder

How do I import/export my custom preferences for Spyder? e.g. if I am installing it on a new machine and would like to import my color/interpreter/keymapping defaults from my original installation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry, there's no way to import/export our Preferences right now.

However, you can look for a directory called `.spyder{-py3}/config` (Windows, macOS) or `~/.config/spyder{-py3}/config` (Linux) in your home or Users directory. That directory contains a file called `spyder.ini`, which has all user preferences. You should be able to copy/paste that file among computers without problems (although we haven't tested that).

If you find any trouble with that method, you can reset your preferences by opening a system terminal (cmd.exe, Terminal.app or xterm) and running there

`spyder --reset`

Comment: has this capability been added? I use many virtual environments, and have to set preferences every time

Comment: No, it hasn't, sorry.

Comment: In 2020 this is not valid anymore, I find neither spyder{-py3} directory, nor spyder.ini on a Ubuntu 18.04 installation.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, is there a way to set a certain `spyder.ini` as system default?
We want to enforce better coding practices at work on shared servers, but it's too troublesome to ask every user to copy this file into their user directory.

Comment: @arustictop, yes, there is. Take a look at the command line option `spyder --paths`. That will show you the places from which Spyder can read its config besides the one I mentioned above. I think you need to place a full `spyder.ini` there with your preferred options, and not simply the options you want to enforce. In other words, you need to take the `spyder.ini` generated from a clear start, customize it as you like, and place it there.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba this is great thanks. I do see that my generated `spyder.ini` has specific paths with my username, for example: under `[plots]` I have `save_dir = C:\Users\username` and `[workingdir]` has `['C:\\Users\\username']`. What would you recommend here? just leave them blank?

Comment: Yeah, you can leave them blank. There shouldn't be a problem with that

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. I overwrite the file but Spyder simply overwrites it again when I launch it. Then my preferences in spyder.ini are gone.

Answer (score 2):

On my computer I have a file
c:\users\xxx.spyder-py3\config\spyder.ini

This file is used by both, Spyder 4.2.5 in Anaconda base environment and by Spyder 5 in a separate venv.